# Can I increase the gameplay speed?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

Is there any way to increase the speed of gameplay in Plants vs. Zombies? It's a great game, but it can get a bit slow.

Comment: I have a similar need but to be able to have to button when clicked will speed up/slow down the game speed - useful when we play endless game and feel confident to call out all of the zombies to... get killed :)

Comment: Cheat Engine offers a way to speed games up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The game offers no such option.

Comment: *makes sad face.*

Comment: I agree @Mechko

Answer (score 4):

Try [Game Speed Adjuster](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/3131-game-speed-adjuster.html).

Comment: unfortunately, I'm a mac.

Answer (score 3):

There is one mini game that speeds the game up. It is called "Zombie Nimble Zombie Quick" but this is only for one level and there is no way to slow it down when needed, so you may get overwhelmed very easily. Otherwise, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

If using PC, install Cheat Engine and use its Speedhack feature.

If using rooted Android, use SB Game Hacker's speedhack feature.

If not rooted, install VMOS through their website, and enable the "virtual root" feature. That way, you don't have to root your actual phone. Then install SB Game Hacker.

If on iOS, can't help, sorry. You'd probably need to jailbreak.